# ROS2 error creating a service server as a member function?

Tags: ros, ros2, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a service server with a callback as a member function:

```
class FirstNode : public rclcpp::Node
  {
    public:
      explicit FirstNode(const std::string & node_name) : Node(node_name)
      {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "%s started", node_name.c_str());
        
        server_ = this->create_service<std_srvs::srv::Trigger>("first_service", std::bind(&FirstNode::handle_service, this, _3, _2, _1));
      }
    
    private:
      void handle_service(
        const std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t> request_header,
        const std::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger::Request> request,
        std::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger::Response> response)
      {
        (void)request_header;
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Service Triggered");
      }
        
      rclcpp::Service<std_srvs::srv::Trigger>::SharedPtr server_;
  };
```

However, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/ahl/happtec_ws/src/first_node_cpp/src/first_node.cpp:15:
In file included from /Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:144:
In file included from /Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21:
In file included from /Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:24:
In file included from /Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/executor.hpp:31:
In file included from /Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node_interfaces/node_base_interface.hpp:25:
In file included from /Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:24:
In file included from /Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/service.hpp:27:
/Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/any_service_callback.hpp:81:46: error: no viable overloaded '='
    shared_ptr_with_request_header_callback_ = callback;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~
/Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/create_service.hpp:43:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'rclcpp::AnyServiceCallback<std_srvs::srv::Trigger>::set<std::__1::__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<3> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>, nullptr>' requested here
  any_service_callback.set(std::forward<CallbackT>(callback));
                       ^
/Users/ahl/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node_impl.hpp:200:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'rclcpp::create_service<std_srvs::srv::Trigger, std::__1::__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<3> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &> >' requested here
  return rclcpp::create_service<ServiceT, CallbackT>(
                 ^
/Users/ahl/happtec_ws/src/first_node_cpp/src/first_node.cpp:43:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'rclcpp::Node::create_service<std_srvs::srv::Trigger, std::__1::__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<3> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &> >' requested here
    server_ = this->create_service<std_srvs::srv::Trigger>("first_service", std::bind(&FirstNode::handle_service, this, _3, _2, _1));
                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1645:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<3> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'const std::__1::function<void (std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >)>' for 1st argument
    function& operator=(const function&);
              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1646:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<3> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'std::__1::function<void (std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >)>' for 1st argument
    function& operator=(function&&) _NOEXCEPT;
              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1647:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<3> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'std::nullptr_t' (aka 'nullptr_t') for 1st argument
    function& operator=(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT;
              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1655:7: note: candidate template ignored: r

    equirement '__callable<typename decay<__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, shared_ptr<Trigger_Request_<allocator<void> > >, shared_ptr<Trigger_Response_<allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const __ph<3> &, const __ph<2> &, const __ph<1> &> &>::type>::value' was not satisfied [with _Fp = std::__1::__bind<void (FirstNode::*)(std::__1::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t>, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Request_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Trigger_Response_<std::__1::allocator<void> > >), FirstNode *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<3> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> &, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &> &]
          operator=(_Fp&&);
          ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299126/ros2-error-creating-a-service-server-as-a-member-function?/) by [ahlyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/36752/ahlyder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2018-07-31**:
You might be interested in the discussion on this stack overflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14 . Some people prefer lambda's instead of `std::bind` since C++14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the arguments to `bind` are out of order. I think it should be

```
std::bind(&FirstNode::handle_service, this, _1, _2, _3));
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahlyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/36752/ahlyder/) on 2018-08-09**:
You're right! I got the order from an example, so I thought that the arguments where passed in the order they appeared and not by number. But is a nice feature.